# DOS attack always from a same Domain - Mitigation

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall

I frequently get dos attacked on UDP with length 0 from

**p885068-ipngn200609sizuokaden.shizuoka.ocn.ne.jp.51422**

I have tried resolving this host to an ip **180.33.161.68** and added the address to iptables to drop it,but iptables doesn't seem to drop it.

Any help? so that i can block this host ,also the length shown is UDP, length 0 ,is there any way to drop such 0 length udp packets

Here are the rules

```
1        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       45.117.26.115        0.0.0.0/0           
2     199K   32M ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       106.193.0.0/16       0.0.0.0/0           
3        0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       202.231.72.67        0.0.0.0/0           
4        0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       180.33.161.68       0.0.0.0/0           
5        0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       8.4.0.0/24           0.0.0.0/0           
6        0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       180.33.0.0/24        0.0.0.0/0           
7        0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       202.231.0.0/16       0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: Could you post the full output from your iptables?  It's possible you have another rule which is matching before these ones.  Plus it would be useful to know your default policy.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If iptables doesn't work, you need to use directly a blackhole route with "ip" command.

For example :

```
ip route add blackhole 180.33.161.68/32
```

The only thing is you can't see if you detect this ip is going to enter or not. (But, you pretty sure that this IP can't communicate anymore)

Comment: Cool, il try that

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the `iptables-save -c` command to list the full rule set.
2. Order of rules is very important. It means the first matched rule wins.
3. To check packets by packet length you can use rule like this, where statement `0:28` will match packets with length from 0 to 28 bytes inclusively (20 bytes of IPv4 header + 8 bytes of UDP header).

```
iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m length --length 0:28 -j DROP
```

4. The `length` match checks the total length field in the IPv4 header, not IPv4 packet payload length.
5. To match by huge list of addresses better use the `ipset`. It works faster than list of rules.
6. The `tcpdump` captures a traffic before processing in the firewall. It means you will see the packets those will be blocked by rules.

Comment: I already have this rule as 1st rule iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m length --length 0:48-j DROP,stil my system is responding to attack

Comment: Check the rule counter. Is this rule matched against packets? Check the traffic with tcpdump, paste lines with these evil packets into the question (`tcpdump -ni <iface> 'udp and ip host X.X.X.X'`).